# Making a DIV float between header and footer

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the below fairly simple java-script function on a webpage with a header, footer and a banner in between the header and footer right side of the body, to make the banner seem to be floating between the header and footer when users scroll the webpage.

```
    $(window).scroll(function()
    {      
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > headerHeight)            
            $(".banner").css("position", "fixed");                        
        else            
            $(".banner").css("position", "relative");
    }
```

I want the banner to be auto scrolled/floated/moved when user scrolls the browser window. The  code works fine: it makes the banner float/move and stops the banner from floating/moving over the header. But I need to add one more condition: the banner must stop floating before the end of webpage is reached because a footer is present. This code now causes the banner to be moving/floating over the footer when user reaches the bottom of the page.

Can anyone help me in getting this condition included in the if block as an or condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you use the stickyfloat jquery plugin!

Demo: http://jsbin.com/eqihef
http://plugins.jquery.com/project/stickyfloat

It's a great little plugin which gives you a lot of control.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you. Let me try.

Comment: this might help too: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/spotlight-constrained-stickies-with-jquer/

Answer (score 1):

You could probably just contain the banner within a container which touches the bottom of the header and the top of the footer, then enable scrolling within it's extents.